# Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am creating an anuglar2 application. I am unable to print the data on the html page from my service. I am getting an error Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined   on my console. Could somebody tell me what the problem is.

**risk-list.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'rm-risks',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{risks}} details!</h2>`,

    providers: [RiskService]
    })  

export class RiskListComponent implements OnInit  {
    title  = 'Risk List';
    risks: Risk[];

    constructor(private _riskService: RiskService) {
      console.log(this.risks);
    }

    getRisks(): void {
        this._riskService.getRisks().then(risks => this.risks = risks);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {                                                                                                                  
        this.getRisks();
    }
};
```

**risk.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { Risks } from './mock-risks';

@Injectable()
export class RiskService {

    getRisks(): Promise<Risk[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(Risks);
    }

}
```

**risk.ts**

```
export class Risk {
    riskId: number;
    reference: string;
    insuredName: string;
    inceptionDate: string;
    riskType: string;
    status: string;
    grossPremium: number;
    allocatedTo: string;
    allocatedCompany: string;

}
```

**mock-risks.ts**

```
import {Risk} from './risk'

export const Risks: Risk[] = [

    {
        riskId: 1,
        reference: "HISC9308336",
        insuredName: "SA 84161",
        inceptionDate: 'March 19, 2016',
        riskType: 'Quote',
        status: 'Indication',
        grossPremium: 100,
        allocatedTo: 'Broker User',
        allocatedCompany: 'Broker'

    }
];
```

**risk-list.component.html**

```
<h3 class="first">{{title}}</h3>

<div>{{risks | json}}</div>
<p-dataTable [value]="risks" [paginator]="true" rows="5" totalRecords="100" pageLinkSize="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]"  [sortMode]="multiple" sortField="inceptionDate" [sortOrder]="1" >
    <header>List of Risks</header>



        <!--<footer>Choose from the list.</footer>-->
        <p-column field="reference" header="Reference (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="insuredName" header="Insured Name (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="inceptionDate" header="Inception Date (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="riskType" header="Risk Type (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="status" header="Status (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="grossPremium" header="Gross Premium (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="allocatedTo" header="Allocated To (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="allocatedCompany" header="Allocated Company (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: I have seen this error come from McAfee chrome extension. Does this error happen to come from ContentScript.js? Do you happen to have McAfee chrome extension installed?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck yup, thats what was causing mine. Good catch!